# Android - Run a function at specific time

Tags: android, android-workmanager, background-service, foreground-service

I have a application that needs to run for long hours in the background. So i'm using foreground service for that. Every 15 min, I need to trigger a function and do some process. For triggering this function I used all the possible ways like `Alarm manager, Work Manager, Handler`
But none of them are working when app goes to background.
Question : What is the best way to trigger a function at specific time, which ensures it will definitely trigger in all the possible scenarios like app in background, foreground and doze.

Answer (score 1):

While most phones out there have their own version of ROM and Work manager completely depends upon the manufacturer. i Quote

> The work manager depends on the device manufacturer. In my case, it is
> an miui device, which does not allow work manager to work in case the
> app is killed or rebooted. The work manager worked when I provided the
> application with "autostart permission".

So *autostart* is a help if you would use that. Now the problem with manufacturers ROM is so varying with Android users , you cannot just depend on one method to have it working on all devices. Bottomline is this

If you want to be on a safer side , and want to run the critical code without failing,  i would suggest you go with a foreground service , write an implementation of timely based triggers and it will run. Basic approach is to use a `TimerTask` or a runnable and post delay it for 15 minutes.

Remember it must be a foreground service , and it comes with a case condition to have a foreground notification running all the time. Now that will be visible to the user and annoy them.

> As a security feature of the Android platform, you cannot, under any
> circumstance, have a foregrounded service without also having a
> notification. This is because a foregrounded service consumes a
> heavier amount of resources and is subject to different scheduling
> constraints (i.e., it doesn't get killed as quickly) than background
> services, and the user needs to know what's possibly eating their
> battery. So, don't do this.
>
> However, it is possible to have a "fake" notification, i.e., you can
> make a transparent notification icon (iirc). This is extremely
> disingenuous to your users, and you have no reason to do it, other
> than killing their battery and thus creating malware.

And if are thinking of hiding notification and it works under android 7.1 it **MAY VIOLATE**
[Google Play's developer policies.](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/malicious-behavior/)

For background service use this

```
//The task which you want to execute
private static class MyTimeTask extends TimerTask
{

    public void run()
    {
        //write your code here
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //the Date and time at which you want to execute
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = dateFormatter .parse("2012-07-06 13:05:45");

    //Now create the time and schedule it
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    //Use this if you want to execute it once
    timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date);

    //Use this if you want to execute it repeatedly
    //int period = 10000;//10secs
    //timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date, period );
}
```